# LWJGL Vector2f slowly change into another vector

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have 2 Vectro2f's from LWJGL. One to store the player position and one to store the mouse-right-click destination for the player to move to. In an update method, provided with the delta time, how could I slowly move the position vector points towards the direction vector points, to make the player move to the select position? I've tried this, but this just makes an instant jump and doesn't go to the proper coordinates each time:

```
if(this.destination != this.position) {
        this.position.setX(this.destination.x-this.position.x);
        this.position.setY(this.destination.y-this.position.y);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put this in your loop:

```
if (destination != position){
  position.setX(position.getX() + dX);
  position.setY(position.getY() + dY);
}
```

where dX and dY are the amount the player should travel in the X and Y directions in one frame.
One way to calculate dX and dY is using trig:

`dX = velocity * Math.cos(theta)` where theta is the angle to the destination from the horizontal (X axis, i.e. the unit circle in trig).

`dY = velocity * Math.sin(theta)`.